# Flip Array Recursively

Tags: c, recursion

There is this problem on LeetCode that I can not get to work in C/C++
The idea is to reverse an array in its place (using no other additional array) using recursion.
The link is : https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/recursion-i/250/principle-of-recursion/1440/
The solution is done in Java or Python.
I tried implementing the solution in C but I always get the original array, my code is as follows:

```
void reverseString(char* s, int sSize){
    if(!s)
        return;
    reverseString(s+1,sSize-1);
    s[sSize] = *s;
}
```

There is something I am not accounting for. Please let me know how would you solve it, and if possible why this is not working. Thanks.

Comment: In a string of size 5, the max index is `s[4]` (among other issues)

Comment: `reverseString(s+1,sSize-1);` -->> `reverseString(s+1,sSize-2);` Plus: the recursion-stopper shpould be ` if (sSize<1) return;`

Comment: OMG @wildplasser that worked! How? Why? I'll have to retrace it

Comment: No, that does *not* work; instead of swapping, it only mirror-copies one half of the string to the other half.

Comment: @wildpasser you mean it doesn't modify the actual array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this.

The general idea for a recursive solution is for each call to get a pointer to the start of a string, and how many characters to look at, and this walks its way to the middle of the string.

```
void reverseString(char *start, int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) return;

    char tmp = start[0];
    start[0] = start[--n];   // the nth character is start[n-1]
    start[n] = tmp;

    reverseString(++start, --n);
}
```

On each recursive call, the starting string pointer is incremented by one, and the length decreased **by two**.

```
FIRST CALL:   v          v
              hello, world
SECOND CALL:   ^        ^
```

The common danger area is making sure it does the right thing with even and odd-length strings.

This method is a bit simpler with just two parameters, and - as some might say - a bit more elegant :-)  even if the `++` and `--` could be considered tricky (one increment and two decrements).

**EDIT**: This version is also [tail recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion), which can lead to certain optimizations by internally turning it into a loop.

Comment: I was about to ask you to write an answer yourself as I was curious about how you'd go about solving this. +1. Aren't increment and decrement operators' behaviors implementation dependent though?

Comment: They're only tricky in that you have to read it closely, but these are all entirely well defined.  I just simplified it a bit: still functions the same, but maybe easier to follow.

Comment: Alright, thank you! I'm fairly new to answering questions on SO, but I'm slowly getting the grasp of it thanks to you helpful comment section people. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, that helps me out alot, I was going about it the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Solution (thank you to the folks in the comments):

```
void reverse(char * str, int len)
{
    char tmp;

    if (len <= 1)
        return;

    tmp = str[0];
    len--;
    str[0] = str[len];
    str[len] = tmp;
    str++;
    reverse(str, len-1);
}
```

Call this function with your initial string and 0 as arguments:

```
char str[] = "Ding dong";

reverse(str, 0, strlen(a));
```

Comment: @ggorlen I have tested and re-read this code and cannot see where it would fail. Could you please develop on that?

Comment: What is the value of `i` the second time you call it?   What happens if it's called by multiple threads?

Comment: @SaucyGoat Call it twice in the same program with different strings.

Comment: @SteveFriedl thank you! I edited accordingly, that was a major oversight on my part. Should be okay now.

Comment: @SaucyGoat It works, but `strlen(str)` scans the whole string making it `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Corrected @ggorlen

Comment: Now you call `reverse()` with 3 parameters: you could dump the "start" parameter by just incrementing the string pointer on subsequent calls.

Comment: @SteveFriedl I don't see how I would do the `if (i == len/2)` confirmation if I don't know in which position of the array I'm in though

Comment: @SaucyGoat - Each call would have a pointer to the first character to look at, and the number of characters to consider. Each call would have ptr+1 and len-1 on subsequent recursive visits until len <= 1;

Comment: @SteveFriedl took me longer than I'd like to admit, but I figured out what you meant. Your solution is way more elegant. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void reverse_string(char *x, int start, int end)
{
    char ch;
    if (start >= end)
       return;

    ch = *(x+start);
    *(x+start) = *(x+end);
    *(x+end) = ch;

    //Function calling itself: Recursion
    reverse_string(x, ++start, --end);
}
```

In this function we are passing the string, the starting index and the ending index.... The recursion will continue till `start>=end` i.e. till the center of the string appears..... And everytime it will swap the 2 indexes i.e. from the start and from the end...

Comment: Please always include some description on why your code should fit as an answer.