# C recursive function to reverse a string without pointers, string.h, or external variables

Tags: c, recursion

I have written a beginner-level program to recursively reverse a string. I use a variable with file scope and strlen(). However, the task seems to be not to use any of those or pointers, and the reverseString function should only receive an array. Is it possible to write a recusive function with such conditions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverseString(char[]);

int i = 0;

int main()
{
    char word[100];

    printf("Write something: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    printf("What you wrote reversed is: ");
    reverseString(word);

    return 0;
}

void reverseString(char string[]) {
    if (string[i] != '\0') {
        ++i;
        printf("%c", string[strlen(string) - i]);
        reverseString(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the function supposed to reverse the characters in the array, or just print them in reverse order?

Comment: A pretty good discussion of recursive string reversal here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438783/flip-array-recursively/59439190#59439190

Comment: You *can't* work with strings in C without using pointers.

Comment: @Shawn CS50 thinks you can :-)

Comment: @SteveFriedl It's wrong, whatever it is.